# How to avoid Python printing a number with scientific notation?

Tags: python, formatting

I know some questions like mine were already posted but my case is a little bit different.
I'd like to avoid scientific notation but I've got a problem: I can't format my output doing `{:.df}` because I don't know the number of digits before running the script. Indeed, this output is the result of computing on an input. Here's something someone advised me to do:

```py
("{:.%df}" % number_of_digits(result[i])).format(result[i])
```

It sadly doesn't work. Here's a bigger piece of code for you to understand well:

```py
result = [n / 1000000**3, n / 100000**3, n / 10000**3, n / 1000**3, n / 100**3, n / 10**3, n]
for i in range(len(volume_units)):
    print(str(n) + ' ' + volume_units[choice - 1] + " = " + ("{:.%df}" % number_of_digits(result[i])).format(result[i]) + ' ' + volume_units[i])
```

Here's the code of `number_of_digits` function:

```py
def number_of_digits(number):
    counter = 0
    while number > 0:
        number //= 10
        counter += 1
    return counter
```

Thanks a lot to people who will answer!

> What does the format of your output look like?

Just like this:
[Output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2X5AN.png)

Comment: What does the format of your numbers look like? Floats? Ints? Negative or positive?

Comment: e just stands for the exponent of 10. For example, a calculator would show the number 25 trillion as either 2.5E13 or 2.5e13

Answer (score 0):

```
length = len(str(abs(your_number)))
format_string = '{:.' + str(length) + 'f}'
print format_string.format(your_number)
```

You'll need to adjust for the formatting type you want and the variable for your number.

Comment: It actually doesn't work. Could it come from the fact I do it in a for loop?

Comment: You know what? I finally decided to keep the scientific notation :)